# C++ ( Without MFC ) Disabling/Graying a menu item

Tags: c++, winapi, menu

I have been having trouble with my program trying to gray out ( and disable ) a sub menu item.

What I'm looking for is that the "run" item be disabled unless the required .ini entry is not empty.

My code

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HMENU hmenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
// Reading in ini
    if (0 == strcmp(webLocation, "")){
    EnableMenuItem(hmenu,ID_WEBSERVICES_RUN,MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
    WritePrivateProfileString(_T("WEBSERVICES"), _T("Location"), _T("Tool Not Found"), WpathStr);
}
```

I am unsure as to whether I am getting the HMENU correctly and why this  code is not working for the desired effect.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put this in the WndProc at the top level. WndProc process events, whether the window has been constructed or not. It'll be called many times for many different reasons.

Your WndProc will almost certainly look like a big switch on `message`. The one you want here is [`WM_INITDIALOG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645428.aspx):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
         case WM_INITDIALOG:
             // jump to a new function that reads the .ini
             // and disables the control etc.
             return OnInitDialog(hWnd, wParam, lParam);

         default:
             return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using paint instead of dialog ( WM_PAINT ). Should I put my code n here ?

Comment: You could perhaps but again WM_PAINT is called lots - once every time any part of the window needs to be re-rendered e.g. if it's no longer obscured by something else or when it's restored after being minimised. If you put your logic in there then you'll need to protect it with a flag so that it only loads the .ini files once. However I think there are better messages to use instead.

Comment: I haven't looked at flags at all yet. Turning a menu item gray is turning out to be more complicated that I originally thought :/. Thanks for your help Rup!

Comment: Could you shed any light on what some other messages might be ?

Comment: I still think that WM_INITDIALOG is the one you want. There was an old tool that Microsoft used to ship with Visual Studio called Spy++ that lists all the messages and makes this easy to debug and understand (albeit once you've filtered the messages down to a reasonable set). Look for Spy in your start menu or 'spyxx' on disk. I don't know what install option it's tied to, though: I had to dig it out of the VS installer cab files (cab23 or cab40 for VS2010 premium). If you can't make it work, you can at least explorer the message list under Messages, Logging Options, Messages.

Comment: Thanks again for the informative response. Ill have a look into replacing PAINT with INITDIALOG as either will do for this scenario.